# Transfer a certain portion to a specific wallet in solidity

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I want to develop a smartcontract where, with every transfer 2% goes to a fixed wallet address.
lets say i am transferring 100 tokens so 2% of that amount should go to the specific wallet.

code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Wallet {

    address public wallet = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
    uint256 public  totalSupply=1000;
    address public owner;
    uint fees =2;

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

  constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _amount)public {
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity does not yet support floating point numbers calculations like `_amount * 0.02`, which would give you the 2 percent that you need.

So, to work around this, we can use another way to get the percentage that you need, which is by dividing.

If you divide whatever number (greater or equal to 100) by 50, you will get the 2 percent that you need as a whole number.

`100 / 50` is 2. Which is the same as `100 * 0.02` in other languages that allow floating point calculations.

`200 / 50` is 4. 4 is 2% of 200.

`1000 / 50` is 20. 20 is 2% of 1000. And so on.

To get different percentages, change the `50` by other numbers.

`100 / 20` is 5. 5 is 5% of 100.

`200 / 20` is 10. 10 is 5% of 200. And so on.

If you need other percentages, you can calculate the percentage that you need in a calculator as usual (200 * 0.05, for a 5% of 200), and then you look for a number that divides 200 and yields the same result.

It would look like this:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Wallet {

    address public wallet = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000;
    address public owner;
    uint public constant FEE = 50; // 2 percent

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) public {
        // Make sure the minimum value sent is at least 100, so when doing _amount / 50 it works alright.
        require(_amount >= 100, "A minimum of 100 need to be sent");
        uint256 fee = _amount / FEE;
        uint256 amountToBeSent = _amount - fee;
        balances[wallet] = fee;
        balances[_to] = amountToBeSent;
    }

}
```

Of course, this would work fine when sending an `_amount` of 100 or more. For less, it would not work right.

In this case, you can try different approaches. Like using a math library for Solidity to help you out. Or some other techniques.

Check here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/simulating-floating-point-division-in-solidity-35b56d2b597e

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, please update the code as per your requirements for your balances or post a more detailed question.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Wallet {

    address public wallet = 0x60C80318657bbc1A72Ddbe9559E8a3224Ba0fAc1;
    uint256 public  totalSupply= 1000*1e18;
    address public owner;
    uint256 transferFeePercentage  = 2;
    // uint256 public transferFee;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    constructor(){
            owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) public payable  {
       require(msg.value >= _amount, "Amount to send should be less than or equal to amount sent to contract");
        require(_to != address(0)); //should be a valid address
        uint256  transferFee = _amount/100 * transferFeePercentage; //your two percent transfer fee;
        (bool walletFeeSuccess,)  = payable(wallet).call{
            value:transferFee
        }("");
        require(walletFeeSuccess,"TransferFee Failed");

        (bool callSuccess,)  = payable(_to).call{
            value: _amount-transferFee
        }("");
        require(callSuccess,"Transfer Failed");

    }

}
```

You can test this on remix!

Here is how the transaction looks

[image]